# best book for cognitive science

Tags: reference-request

I am computer science student and I have a limited knowledge about cognitive science.

What books would give me a good introduction to the area?

Answer (score 2):

For a neuroscience focused overview I enjoyed:

["Making up the Mind" by Chris Frith](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/581365.Making_Up_the_Mind)

For a psychology textbook ( I think this is used in undergraduate level):

["Psychology 2nd Edition" by  Daniel L. Schacter, Daniel T. Gilbert, Daniel M. Wegner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1429237198)